# Arranging from two columns not arranging

Tags: r

I have been doing most of my data cleaning in excel but I am moving to R. So, I am a new R user. I am trying to find the difference in the two bednights columns from the clients. I want to make sure that when I am subtracting, that I am subtracting from apples to apples and not apple to Banana. The code below is what I put in; however, the result is not what I was looking for.

```
ComparingeEnrollment %>%
   arrange(`FullNameFruit1.1`, `Full name`) %>%
   mutate(Difference = BednightsFruit1.1 - sum_Bednights)
```

When you look at the way the names of the clients are arranged.I can see that they are not both arranged. Only one is. [Picture of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvfMA.png), For example, you will see apple, banana, pear, versus apple, banana, blue berry. This throws my calculations because I am not subtracting from the correct client. This is easy to do in excel and I believe it can be easy in R but I do not know how to do it.

Google tables link to access the data.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/189nj0a_SCvDFKmaDJUNjJRsOWizkuxhJfA1-a2s87r0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Share just enough data to be representative for your problem, the code that you have tried and expected output. This will make much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `arrange` works as expected here see `?arrange`. I think you need `dplyr::group_by`.

Comment: Add data using `dput(df)` not links to Google docs.